# Some applications (like Terminal) will lose focus after switching Spaces

Tags: macos, spaces

I have the following problem with Spaces in Mountain Lion:

- 1) Open Safari (or Chrome)
- 2) Open Terminal
- 3) Give Terminal window focus
- 4) Switch to Dashboard Space (or any other Space)
- 5) Switch back to Space with Terminal

Expected: Terminal still has focus
Actual: Safari gets focus

This problem can also be duplicated with other applications, such as Adium in place of Terminal. I'm not sure why it affects some apps and not others.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it with Safari and Terminal on 10.8. Does it depend on the settings in the Mission Control preference pane?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't appear to depend on those settings Lri. Odd that you can't reproduce on your system.

Comment: I can also duplicate the same problem stitching between MS Excel 2011 and Preview running 10.8.1.